# String to Leet (1337) Speak in PHP

Tags: php, string

Does anyone know where I can find a good starting point to code a function that would take a string and convert it to leet speak?

```
function stringToLeetSpeak($string) {
  // Logic

  return $leetString;
}
```

Comment: Thought l33t speak was confined to the likes of dalnet, undernet irc channels, y'know those that end up on bash.org...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be my go:

```
class Leetify
{
    private $english = array("a", "e", "s", "S", "A", "o", "O", "t", "l", "ph", "y", "H", "W", "M", "D", "V", "x"); 
    private $leet = array("4", "3", "z", "Z", "4", "0", "0", "+", "1", "f", "j", "|-|", "\\/\\/", "|\\/|", "|)", "\\/", "><");
    function encode($string)
    {
        $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
        {
            $char = $string[$i];

            if (false !== ($pos = array_search($char, $this->english))) 
            {
                $char = $this->leet[$pos]; //Change the char to l33t.
            }
            $result .= $char;
        }
        return $result; 
    } 

    function decode($string) 
    {
        // Just reverse the above.
    }
}
```

Small usage example:

```
$Leet = new Leetify();
$new_leet_text = $Leet->encode("i want this text here to bee leetified xD");
```

Hope this helps.

Notes:

- This is for individual chars only, "Cannot convert whole words"
- This is for demonstration and code may not be perfect.
- My advice is to research string functions and arrays in PHP, also creating a range index so you can combine word + char replacing by using a 3rd array to store string values and there offsets.

Comment: you may have array('a' => '4') and add some excludes, so smiles wouldn't bee leetified

Comment: yea well he can do all the smaller things if he wishes to use it, I just copied the array over.

Comment: Gumbo, im not working out each individual issue, he wishes to know 'how' to convert, not the perfect conversion class, he did also state he wanted a starting point :)

Comment: @RobertPitt: But your code implies that it also works with strings containing more than a single character.

Comment: Oooh i totally missed that :) sorry.

Comment: That rocks, i will make changes and use right away. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) to translate certain characters:

```
$output = strtr($str, 'let', '137');
```

Or use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) with arrays:

```
$output = str_replace(array('l','e','t'), array('1','3','7'), $str);
```

With this you can also replace strings and not just single characters:

```
$output = str_replace(array('hacker'), array('hax0r'), $str);
```

Comment: what about 5? or + for tee or \/ for v, or even \/\/ for w, and 0 for o.... :P might be easier to use a lookup table...

Comment: @tommieb75: Sorry, I don’t understand.

Comment: I think he's referring to characters that translate to multiple-character strings, like how the letter V translates to a backslash followed by a forward slash (`\/`).

Answer (score 4):

Make a 256 string array as an latin character to L33t table. Walk over the string using the character ASCII value as an index into your array. Replace where necessary.

EDIT: Using string to capture BoltClock's insight that some translations require multiple characters.

Comment: 256? What for? latin characters have 65-90 & 97-122 charcodes in ASCII. you need 50 (or 64 ;) character array.

Comment: @Andrew If you want to calculate offsets for each of those 50-64 characters. It's a tradeoff, but if you fill the whole 256 length array, you're guaranteed to have a hit without any calculations.

Comment: it's more like C, not PHP-way (assoc arrays), but l33t enough :)

Answer (score 2):

I just improved Leetify (performance, etc)

https://gist.github.com/romanitalian/04541ec4b621c0b6ca76
[Leetify](https://gist.github.com/romanitalian/04541ec4b621c0b6ca76)

```
/**
 * Class Leetify
 * Leetify::encode('leet'); // "133+"
 * Leetify::decode('133+'); // "leet"
 */
class Leetify
{
    private $string = '';
    private $english = array("a", "e", "s", "S", "A", "o", "O", "t", "l", "ph", "y", "H", "W", "M", "D", "V", "x");
    private $leet = array("4", "3", "z", "Z", "4", "0", "0", "+", "1", "f", "j", "|-|", "\\/\\/", "|\\/|", "|)", "\\/", "><");
    private static $inst = null;
    private static function getInstance() {
        if(is_null(self::$inst)) {
            self::$inst = new self();
        }
        return self::$inst;
    }
    private function run($isEncode = false) {
        $out = '';
        if($this->string) {
            $dict = $isEncode ? $this->english : $this->leet;
            $dict_ = $isEncode ? $this->leet : $this->english;
            $flippedDict = array_flip($dict); // for good performance
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($this->string); $i++) {
                $char = $this->string[$i];
                $out .= isset($flippedDict[$char]) ? $dict_[$flippedDict[$char]] : $char;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
    public function setString($string) {
        $t = self::getInstance();
        $t->string = $string;
        return $t;
    }
    public static function encode($string) {
        return self::getInstance()->setString($string)->run(true);
    }
    public static function decode($string) {
        return self::getInstance()->setString($string)->run();
    }
}
```